# How to write join of multiple graphs

Tags: graph-theory, notation

Let $\overline{K}_{a_i}$ denote a null graph on $a_i$ vertices where $1\le i\le n$.
I want to do join of   $\overline{K}_{a_i}$.

I am not able to  understand how to write join of the graphs $\overline{K}_{a_i}$ mathematically.

Can someone please help me to write it down formally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you might denote graph join with $+$ (in which case you'd write $\overline{K}_{a_1} + \overline{K}_{a_2} + \dots + \overline{K}_{a_n}$) or with $\vee$ (in which case we have an additional option: $\overline{K}_{a_1} \vee \overline{K}_{a_2} \vee \dots \vee \overline{K}_{a_n}$ can also be $\bigvee_{i=1}^n \overline{K}_{a_i}$).

In this particular case, the join of empty graphs with $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ vertices happens to be the complete multipartite graph $K_{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n}$ which has its own notation. (Provided that $n>1$.)